# Laravel Blade HTML ENTITIES

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

From the documentation of Laravel 10:
*By default, Blade (and the Laravel e function) will double encode HTML entities. If you would like to disable double encoding, call the Blade::withoutDoubleEncoding method from the boot method of your AppServiceProvider*

Why would I desable this feature ?

I just want to have information about the use case of desabling it